# Javascript Selenium Chrome WebDriver - proper way to handle alert

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to close alert that sometimes appear when me selenium script running. It is block a click option for specific div that I'm handling in try catch options. When this exception occure, 'm trying to use driver function but it generates ,,NoSuchAlertError".

This some part of my code:

```
let driver = await new Builder()
    .withCapabilities(options)
    .forBrowser("chrome")
    .build(); 

// .. some other logic like get website etc. ... //

    try {
        let dataFromButton= await getDataFromButton(driver); // it fails when alert appear on screen
    } catch (e) {
        let alert = await driver.switchTo().alert(); // it throws NoSuchAlertError
    }
```

[Here is my alert popup, that I'm trying to remove - click on cancel button or call escape key would be enough solution for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5B00.png)

Is there any special ,,alerts" that should be handled in other way than my example ?

Comment: Are you sure it's an alert and not just a popup wiindow? See https://www.guru99.com/alert-popup-handling-selenium.html

Comment: Yes, I have tried methods from your link and it always return the same one window (the same id).

Comment: Is alert is displayed on screen load?

Comment: @YaDavMaNish when it first time appear, it is still visible (my script loading the same page for diffrent resources and it is still visible on every changing of pages - so it is also visibile when page is loading but it dissapear when i open a new tab in browser)

Comment: I mean, it doesn't appear in another tab browser, when I open the same page.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found solution for chrome I use this code:

```
await driver.executeScript('window.stop();');
```

Comment: nice! glad you were able to figure it out.